# In CodeMirror, bind `%%` to autocomplete and add `%%` after the chosen option

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, codemirror

I have a project that want to have CodeMirror implemented. Basically, one of the requirements is that you can type double `%` (for example: %% keyword %%) to display a list (a hint). I have seen the official example with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but I'm wondering how I can make typing the second percent character of the start double percent be a trigger to show the hint list, and how I can display the keyword with the end double percent after choosing an option from the list. I need help or any demo or sample code.

Comment: anyone? please help T_T

Comment: I solved this question since nobody gives the answer. basically, you need the text not displayText to append extra double percent chars. and bind a keyup event to detect if the previous type string is %%.

Comment: When you solve the question yourself, it is best to post your solution as a self-answer instead of a comment. Then you can mark it as accepted, and other people can vote it up and edit it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having similar problems with CodeMirror, I'll share what I have learned.

> type double `%` (for example: %% keyword %%) to display a list (a hint).

To achieve this, first you need to handle the `'change'` event:

```
var cm = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('textArea'),
{
  mode:        'your_custom_language',
  lineNumbers: true,
  extraKeys:   {'Ctrl-Space': 'autocomplete'}
});

var onChange = function(instance, object)
{
    // do stuff...
}

CodeMirror.on(cm, 'change', onChange);
```

Then, on the `onChange` function you must do the following:

1. Check if the last inserted character is `%`.
2. Check if the previous character is `%`.
3. Summon the hint list.

I did it this way:

```
var onChange = function(instance, object)
{
    // Check if the last inserted character is `%`.
    if (object.text[0] === '%' &&
        // Check if the previous character is `%`.
        instance.getRange({ch: object.to.ch - 1, line: object.to.line}, object.to) === '%')
    {
        // Summon the hint list.
        CodeMirror.showHint(cm, CodeMirror.hint.your_custom_language);
    }
}
```

Note that I use the `cm` object previously declared, you must change this to meet your requirements. And also, the deduced context for your keyword will not match what you're expecting; in order to fix this you need to modify your own `codemirror/addon/hint/your_custom_language-hint.js`; in my case, I based my custom language on JavaScript (refactoring the `javascript-hint.js`) modifying the function called `maybeAdd` from:

```
function maybeAdd(str) {
  if (str.lastIndexOf(start, 0) == 0 && !arrayContains(found, str)) found.push(str);
}
```

to:

```
function maybeAdd(str)
{
  if (isValidHint(str))
  {
    found.push({text: '%%' + str + '%%', displayText: str});
  }
}
```

Note that the array `found` of `getCompletions` is no longer storing strings, it is storing objects with this format:

```
{
    // this will be written when the hint is selected.
    "text": "%%text%%",
    // this will be shown on the hint list.
    "displayText": "text",
    // You can custom each hint match with a CSS class.
    "className": "CSSClass"
}
```

Please, note that all the things I've writed above are refactoring of my CodeMirror custom language, it is untested on your own custom language but I hope it helps.

BTW; I think that CodeMirror documentation doesn't look clear and lacks on examples of many demanded features.